# How do I write a regular expression to find all not commented out System.out

Tags: regex

In this project of ours the previous developers had coded throughout System.out even though told to only use the log.[debug,error etc.].

Been trying to write a RE to find all of the System.out that are not commented out but not having much luck. I did find here in the forumns information on negative lookbehind which sounds like what I need but I'm either getting all System.out including the commented ones or nothing at all in my efforts.

Appreciate any guidance on this. Here it the last regular expression I tried `((?<!\\)(?<!\s*))system.out`

Comment: What language is your code? What comment styles do you encounter? For example, if Java, then you need to search for `//` as well as `/*`. If multiple languages, e.g. you've got Javascript and HTML, then you'll need to account for all of the different ways you can comment something out. It might be easier just to look for `System.out` and ignore the results that are commented out (or delete them because unused code is crufty and adds clutter).

Comment: Right now I'm just focusing on all single line comments in JAVA the \\. There were a couple thousand files found looks like most have comments so I want to only find the uncommented ones.

Comment: Additionally, the spacing may be a space or tab or combination in the files.

Comment: I am able to locate System.out with the // using `/\t*\s*System.out` but I'm not clear on the negative lookbehind notation (?<!/\t*\s*)System.out. With this statement I keep getting "Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 10".  Still working on this will post when I resolve.

Comment: Running the regex in Java ? I don't think it has variable length lookbehind (afik). What is the source text language, Java as well ?

Comment: I am using the Eclipse tool to try and search Java code. Does Eclipse support negative lookbehind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` and `$` match the beginning and the end of the *line* in Java. Also `\` has to be escaped in Java Strings.

This is not perfect, but gives an idea, it tries to find `System.out` at the beginning of a line and then matches everything until `;` over multiple lines if necessary:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[ \\t]*System\\.out[^;]+");
// or "^[ \\t]*System\\.out\\.print(?:ln)?\\(.*?\\);"

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(...);
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but, this is something that I would be using in a Java file. I'm looking for doing this in Eclipse the search feature so this answer does not apply to me.

Comment: @Elijah the regex will stay the same, just remove " and replace double \ by single \